How many LocalDate objects are created
How many LocalDate objects are created in this example
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.now();
d1.plusDays(1);
d1 = d1.minusMonths(2);
LocalDate d2 = d1.plusWeeks(3);
d2.minusDays(4);
d2 = null;


LocalDate is an immutable object
I expect to have 5 objects created

(it is possible that now() is re-using an already created instance, but there are 5 instances involved in posted code)

4 LocalDates created

if that is the first usage of LocalDate (class being loaded/initialized) and with Java 21: 8 instances (MIN,  MAX, EPOCH, now(), plusDays(1), minusMonth(2), plusWeeks(3), minusDays(4)) -- Java 8 for example is missing EPOCH

In Java8  source code it looks like anyway it creates new object
//github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalTime.java#L456
private static LocalTime create(int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond) {
...
return new LocalTime(hour, minute, second, nanoOfSecond);
}

I suspect the down-votes are due to your lack of explanation. Edit the Question to give the specifics of your concern or curiosity.

On my system just loading the class LocalDate created 3 instances (MIN, MAX and EPOCH) and calling LocalDate.now() created a whopping 42 additional instances (one for today and 41 while loading the ZoneRules for my time zone).

I was going to say between 0 and 5 and likely the last. But @ThomasKläger convinced me that an older saying can also be true here: “The answer is 42”. ;-) In any case each of those answers would describe a correct behaviour of the library.

Don’t know, don’t care
If the java.time classes were regular plain-vanilla classes, then you would be correct: Five instantiations of LocalDate, five new objects.
Value-based classes
But the java.time classes such as LocalDate are not regular classes. To quote the Javadoc for LocalDate:

This is a value-based class; programmers should treat instances that are equal as interchangeable and should not use instances for synchronization, or unpredictable behavior may occur. For example, in a future release, synchronization may fail. The equals method should be used for comparisons.

And notice how you cannot call new on the java.time classes. The constructors are private to prevent you from explicitly constructing a fresh new object.
Cache
Putting this all together means the java.time classes are free to cache and re-use objects. And those classes are free to instantiate fresh new objects. We as calling programmers do not know which is happening when. And the documentation tells us to not care.
So, how many objects are created by your code? Somewhere between zero to five LocalDate objects, are created, with the remainder of five coming from a theoretically possible cache.
Immutable objects
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.now();
d1.plusDays(1);

The java.time classes use immutable objects. So the second line instantiates (or accesses from a theoretically possible internal cache) another separate LocalDate object. So two LocalDate objects are involved here in these two lines of code.
But then you do nothing with the reference returned to you by your call to plusDays. So that reference is lost.
The second object, for tomorrow, becomes a candidate for garbage collection if not referenced anywhere else including any theoretically possible cache internal to the java.time framework.
Furthermore, the compiler may recognize the futility of your second line. If so the compiler may choose to discard that line entirely. I cannot predict with certainty as I am no expert on the various Java compilers. See Wikipedia to learn about optimizing compiler.
If the compiler does optimize away those lines, we are left with three LocalDate objects, not five. Your code effectively becomes the following:
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.now();  // One `LocalDate` object.
// d1.plusDays(1);  
d1 = d1.minusMonths(2);          // Second `LocalDate` object.
LocalDate d2 = d1.plusWeeks(3);  // Third `LocalDate` object.
// d2.minusDays(4);
d2 = null;

Now, let’s rewrite that code.
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.now();
d1 = d1.plusDays(1);

Now we see two different objects assigned to the same reference variable at different times.

The date object for today’s date is assigned to the reference variable.
Then we re-assign that reference variable to another object representing tomorrow’s date.

The first object, for today, becomes a candidate for garbage collection if not referenced anywhere else including any theoretically possible cache internal to the java.time framework.
Ancillary objects
As commented by Kläger, many other classes and objects may be involved in producing your LocalDate object. He reports dozens of objects instantiated for constants and for time zone rules.

To an optimizing (at runtime) compiler, LocalDate d2 = d1.plusWeeks(3); is also unnecessary when it is immediately followed by d2 = null;. Though, if d1 is not touched by subsequent code (which has not posted here), it is also considered unused, so the entire code could be replaced by “do nothing”. But even if you use the objects, an optimizing compiler may eliminate the objects, especially the temporary ones, and only keep the values actually used by the code.

Here ...

LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.now();


... a reference to one LocalDate instance is returned and assigned to variable d1.  The referenced object might or might not be newly created, but the method invocation ensures that at least one LocalDate instance is created at some point during the execution of the program prior to that invocation's return.
This ...

d1.plusDays(1);


... does not mutate the object referenced by d1, as LocalDate is documented to be immutable, plus this method's specific docs say explicitly that the instance on which it is invoked is not modified.  That the returned reference is ignored is immaterial.  As with now(), the object is not necessarily newly-created, but the invocation ensures that a second LocalDate instance is created at some point during the execution of the program prior to the return.
Similarly, this ...

d1 = d1.minusMonths(2);


... does not mutate the object initially referenced by d1, even though the reference returned is stored in d1, replacing the reference previously stored there.  A reference to an object is not the object itself.  The date designated by this object necessarily differs from those designated by the other two, so this requires a third LocalDate instance to have been created before this invocation returns.
Likewise, these ...

LocalDate d2 = d1.plusWeeks(3);
d2.minusDays(4);


... require two additional LocalDate instances to have been created before the time those invocations return.
But this ...

d2 = null;


... does not require any object to be created.  null is a reference value that does not refer to any object.
Overall, in a program in which all those statements are executed, at least five distinct LocalDate instances will be created by the time the last one is executed, but not necessarily as a direct consequence of those invocations.  It is possible for some or all of them to exist even before the now().

the number of LocalDate objects created in the example code is 5.

Not necessarily. As a value-based class, instances could theoretically be cached and re-used rather than created. See my Answer.

BTW just writing it is 5 is not that helpful (you could also just say it is 4 or whatever)
